# Open community "ask question" modal programatically

Tags: community, aura, experience-cloud

I would like to be able to open the `ask question` modal in communities with my own button, but I can't find any sort of information or related information about it.  I even tried to inspect with the dev console to try to figure out how Salesforce is opening the box without any result.

What I'm doing right now is an old trick where I put the ask question button component on top of my custom button with an `opacity:0`, but that doesn't quite seem to be the right answer or approach at least. Ultimately I would like to have absolute control over when to open the modal.

Comment: I was going to submit same/similar question - how do I open the forceCommunity:askCommunity dialog via aura or LWC? I would like to direct my users directly to it, and specify a preset topic for them in the dialog.

Comment: Did you figure out the link to follow to open the modal?

Comment: @Patlatus I've posted my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work-around this.  I was able to get the URL via meta data (in APEX) and use that to create the link that will redirect the user to the community/questions. (Note: Doesn't actually open the "Ask Question" modal, but directs the user to the page where they can click it... hopefully others find this helpful.)

Below are the necessary code snippets:

LWC-HTML:

```
        <lightning-button label="Agent Community / Ask a Question" variant="brand" onclick={handleBtn_AgentCommunity}>
        </lightning-button>
```

LWC-JS:

```
import AC_getNetworkSwitchURL from '@salesforce/apex/agentCommunityController.getNetworkSwitchURL';

...

@track theNetworkSwitchURL;

connectedCallback() {
    AC_getNetworkSwitchURL()
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) this.theNetworkSwitchURL = result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('AC_getNetworkSwitchURL Error', error);
        });
}//connectedCallback


handleBtn_AgentCommunity() {
    window.open(this.theNetworkSwitchURL, '_blank');
}//handleBtn_AgentCommunity
```

APEX (agentCommunityController):

```
public static final String NetworkName = 'Agent Community';
public static Id theNetworkId;
public static String theNetworkURL;
public static String theNetworkSwitchURL;

static {
    List<Network> lstNetworks = [ SELECT Id, Name, UrlPathPrefix 
                                    FROM Network
                                    WHERE Name = :NetworkName ];
    if ( lstNetworks == null || lstNetworks.size() == 0 ) { System.debug('ERROR: Network Not Found [' + NetworkName + ']'); return; }

    List<Site> lstSites = [ SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Name, Subdomain, UrlPathPrefix 
                            FROM Site 
                            WHERE MasterLabel = :NetworkName 
                            AND UrlPathPrefix = :lstNetworks[0].UrlPathPrefix ];
    if ( lstSites == null || lstSites.size() == 0 ) { System.debug('ERROR: Site Not Found [' + NetworkName + ']'); return; }

    List<SiteDetail> lstSiteDetails = [ SELECT SecureUrl 
                                        FROM SiteDetail 
                                        WHERE DurableId = :lstSites[0].Id ];
    if ( lstSiteDetails == null || lstSiteDetails.size() == 0 ) { System.debug('ERROR: SiteDetails Not Found [' + NetworkName + ']'); return; }

    theNetworkId = lstNetworks[0].Id;
    theNetworkURL = lstSiteDetails[0].SecureUrl;
    theNetworkSwitchURL = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/servlet/networks/switch?networkId=' + theNetworkId.to15();
}

@AuraEnabled public static String getNetworkSwitchURL () {
    return theNetworkSwitchURL;
}//getNetworkSwitchURL
```

Also note, you can create links to specific Topics or Questions by using the ID of the Topic or Question:

```
theNetworkSwitchURL + '&startURL=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/s/topic/' + TOPICID, 'UTF-8')

theNetworkSwitchURL + '&startURL=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/s/question/' + QUESTIONID, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: I asked this in 2016, briefly worked with the salesforce community solution back then, incredible that is 2022, and you need so much complexity to do a simple thing.